# Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex error with PERL

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to change a line using Regex and a hash table containing the changes. I'm using the next code to change:

```
    foreach $key (keys %{$hash{$sub_hash}}){
        $line =~ s/$key/$hash{$csub_hash}{$key}/g;
    }
```

And my hash is:

```
    $hash{sub_hush_a}={
    "\\mi2ie..."    =>  "\\RSUop...",
    "iereset..."    =>  "\\agres...",
};
```

The problem is that for the first pair in the data set, when ever it changes it puts`\\` instead of `\`, and for the second one only puts one, as expected.

As well it gives me the error:
`Unrecognized escape \m passed through`.
What is wrong?

*clarification*: the dots in the names are not there in the program, the names are longer than what I put, and are all containing only letters and digits. the dots are here in order to shorten.

**EDIT:**

The problem fixes, (the double `\` and the error message) if I change the fist pair to:

`"mi2ie..." =>  "RSUop...",` (remove the `\\`).

But I still want to know what is the problem, as in the future I might need to add other values that may cause the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have this issue because **your strings have sequences treated as special in the Regex**. So you need to escape/quote this sequences. Here is Perl so called *Dirty Dozen*:

> \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? .

This will fix it (the `\Q..\E` will quote such metacharacters):

```
foreach $key (keys %{$hash{$sub_hash}}){
    $line =~ s/\Q$key\E/$hash{$csub_hash}{$key}/g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into problems because you're using string literals as a regexp, and using backslashes in a string literal is interpreted differently than using backslashes in a regexp.

You can get around this by storing regexps in your hash instead of string literals, using the `qr` operator (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: qr doesn't help here, it changes what it was given into something else. It adds and changes so that It'll be in regex language.

Comment: Since the offending characters are in the hash _keys_, qr won't help, because a hash key can only be a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $line = 'test\mi2ie...test';

sub replace($$$) {
   my ($str, $what, $replacement) = @_;
   my $pattern = quotemeta($what);
   $str =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;
   return $str;
}

my %hash;
my $sub_hash = "test";
$hash{$sub_hash} = {
    '\mi2ie...'    =>  '\RSUop...',
    'iereset...'    =>  '\agres...',
};

while (my ($key, $value) = each %{$hash{$sub_hash}}) {
    $line = replace($line, $key, $value);
}

print "$line\n";
```